# Row re-order with angular-datatables

Tags: angular, datatables, row, angular-datatables

Is this possible to use row reorder with angular-datatables ?
I am using angular-datatables npm for display data in table, i need to do row reorder task in may angular-datatables's table how its possible.

i am used listing like https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/basic/angular-way
and need listing like https://editor.datatables.net/examples/extensions/rowReorder

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser
For inclusion of this library using a standard  tag, rather than using this package, it is recommended that you use the [DataTables download builder](https://datatables.net/download/)DataTables download builder which can create CDN or locally hosted packages for you, will all dependencies satisfied.

npm

```
npm install datatables.net-rowreorder-dt
```

```
var $ = require( 'jquery' );
require( 'datatables.net-rowreorder-dt' )( window, $ );
```

bower

```
bower install --save datatables.net-rowreorder-dt
```